# adding border around controls dynamically...asp.net

Tags: asp.net, dynamic, controls, panel

My ASP.NET application allows the user to create their own screens. They can, for example, drag controls like textboxes, combos, etc and place them on the desginer. Now, they want to group specific controls in a box. For example, all the Basic information such as User name, address, age ,DOB etc should be surrounded by a single box (like..group box control). The code on runtime, dynamically places all these controls to create a page.

I tried to achieve this using a Panel control with a black border. This works fine, but when I  add a background color to the panel, I no longer see the controls inside the panel. They are hidden.

Is there any good to achieve this. Please help.

Comment: z-index of the other controls maybe?

Comment: Is the code that dynamically places all the controls to create the page inside of the Panel doing anything besides Panel.Controls.Add() calls?

Comment: it does not use Panel.Controls.Add()